# value of variable in Veriog not defined

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I am analyzing a verilog file for always.

in this, what should be the value of "en" in case first and then in second?

```
always @(in1, in2, en) begin
    out = in2;
    if(en) begin

        out = in1;
```

where in1, in2 and en are three input declared already and out is output.

is it will be 0 in first case and 1 in second case?

Comment: What do you mean by the "first case" and the "second case"?

Comment: first case is when  beign out = in2 and second case when if(en ) begin

Comment: Those aren't separate cases, they both (notionally) happen whenever any of the inputs (in1, in2, en) change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined register values usually start at the special value "X", and unconnected wires at "Z".

I can't make sense of your question, because you say that "en" is an input defined already and then ask what its value should be.

That block fragment shown will set `out` to the value of `in1` if `en` is not zero. If `en` is zero then it will set `out` to the value of `in2`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here, title does not seem to match the question.

But your example is the same equivalent to :

```
always @(in1, in2, en) begin
  if(en == 1'b1) begin
    out = in1; 
  end
  else begin
    out = in2;
  end
end
```

Hope fully this makes it clear that unless en is 1 out will be assigned to the value of in2.

I would personally change the sensitivity list from `@(in1, in2, en)` to `@*` this avoids simulation funnies from appearing by missing signals.